# nested requests in angular 2 HttpClient

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular2-nativescript

I'm new in making http requests using angular's subscribe, so I don't know if it is possible (but I made it once with promises)
I use in my nativescript app the angular HttpClient with my own interceptor, where I add the Authorization header like https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses

The token I get expires in 25 minutes, so I would catch the 401 response, make a new login request and retry the original request again with the new token.

so I made somethink like this (isn't working):

```
...
next.handle(newRequest)
        .catch((response: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                return next.handle(new HttpRequest("POST", loginUrl, credentials))
                        .subscribe((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                                BackendService.token = event.body.token;
                                return next.handle(newRequest).subscribe();
                            }
                        })
                    );
            }
            return Observable.throw(response);
        })
```

I realized it once using promises (in a custom service) like:

```
request.catch((response: HttpErrorResponse) => {
   if(response.status === 401) {
      return http.post(loginUrl, credentials)
          .then(response => {
              return requestWithNewToken;
          }, error => {
              ... redirect UI to login -> login with saved credentials failed
          })
   }
})
```

I would like to handle it all via Interceptors insted of a service.

Comment: You return next.handle and pass some params to it. It might be wrong. I think you need to return an Observable where you do your extra request and you should mergeMap it to next.handle. Something like `return this.http.post('get-new-token', someData).mergeMapTo(next.handle(response))`

Comment: `next.handle` returns an `Observable`. the problem is that I dont want do `mergeMapTo` both requests every time, but to try the request first and if it failes (token is expired) return them (login request and same request with new token)

Comment: "if it failes". yep. thats why you put your code into `.catch`. something like this then: `return next.handle(req).mergeMap((data) => if error then return this.http.post('get-new-token', someData).mergeMapTo(next.handle(response)) else return Observable.throw(request)).subscribe()`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm really new in handling observables. trying your example: how can I handle the `if error` in the `mergeMap` method? here I get only once a `HttpEvent` from type 0

Answer (score 1):

ok, aftersome time of hard trying I solved it:

```
return next.handle(newRequest)
        .catch((res: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (res.status === 401) {
                return next.handle(new HttpRequest("POST", loginUrl, credentials))
                    .mergeMap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                            //save new token somewhere
                            //return a clone of the request replacing Authorization header with new token
                            return next.handle(newRequest.clone({ headers: newRequest.headers.set("Authorization", event.body.token) }));
                        }
                        return Observable.of(event);
                    });
            }
            return Observable.throw(res);
        })
```